# How to print request and response message in SoapUI result xml

Tags: windows, testing, command-line, soapui

I am trying to execute some tests in SoapUI via command line.

**Command example:**

```
C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.2.1\bin\testrunner.bat -s
"TestSuite 1" -c "Test001" -M -j -f "c:\auto" -r "C:\soapui-project.xml"
```

And output file is something like that:

```
<con:testCaseRunLog ...>
    <con:testCaseRunLogTestStep name="step 1 name" status="OK" ... />
    <con:testCaseRunLogTestStep name="step 2 name" status="OK" ... />
    <con:testCaseRunLogTestStep name="step 3 name" status="FAILED" ...>
        <con:message>[LA is valid] XPathContains assertion failed for path [//Row[1]/EXTERNAL_ID[1]] : Exception:Missing content for xpath [//Row[1]/EXTERNAL_ID[1]] in Response</con:message>
    </con:testCaseRunLogTestStep>
</con:testCaseRunLog>
```

At this time prints only the assertions when failling. I don't understand much of SoapUI but how can I print or configure some log to include soap requests/responses or queries/results(steps with JDBC) in output file for each step?

**Examples:**

```
<con:request>...</con:request>
<con:response>...</con:response>
```

or more tags like:

```
<con:message>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the either the `-a` or `-A` flags from command line?

Comment: "-A" complicates a little bit the parse of detailed results with folders and sub-folders.
"-a" can work but also keeps the results in separated files and I have to parse each one. But if I can't find a better and simple way(in the same file) I will give a shot to "-a" approach. Thank you.

Comment: All are concatenated into `soapui.log`.

Comment: OK, "-a" did the job but in a JDBC step the log file appears without messages. Its normal because there is no messages exchanged. Only the query and the result. Is it possible to include that in log file?

Comment: @koxta, you mean to say that request and response to be available in soapui.log? Isn't it available now? Have you also checked script log?

Answer (score 0):

With **-a** flag in command, SoapUI stores result for each step in a separated file. This solves the problem.